# Float logo to the left, and content to the right

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have the following `HTML` and `CSS`, where the logo floats on the left side, but I'd like to be able to have the content float on right side.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="images/logo.gif" height="376" width="198" alt="LOGO" title="" />
    </div>
    <div id="maintext">
      <p id="main">First paragraph</p>
      <p>Second paragraph.</p>
    </div>
    <footer>...</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my CSS, the selector for `logo` is:

```
#logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

#maintext {
  padding: 0 0.5em 0 0.5em;
}
```

What's happening is that the logo "`images/logo.gif`" shows up to the left side of but on top of the footer. It should show up on the left side of the "maintext" selector.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this CSS:

```
footer {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand... it would be:

```
float: right;
```